What is a fool proof future-world CAPTCHA test, given that AI can bypass current-day CAPTCHA's?
We are getting to the point today where AI could solve all current CAPTCHA tests, such that if someone were accessing data remotely there is no way the website would know if it is a real human, or an AI.
Current day CAPTCHA tests normally use distorted images of fire hydrants, bicycles or traffic lights to tell if a person is human, rating performance on a score to see if it was an automated image recognition technique that deciphered them. Recently, ChatGPT-4o has been demonstrated to be able to bypass these CAPTCHA's.
In a future, space-faring world (say a dozen years from now), what test can be provided by an online remote (assume government) service to definitively prove a person is human - or is this actually an impossible task now?
Assume the AI:

already has access to all the published literature works of humanity
has access to all the image libraries that reside publicly online
does not have a 'physical' presence, and interaction with the other party can only be visual, audio or intellectual. Therefore, 'physical-based' answers are unacceptable.
the person on the service / running the service can be a human if you like - to try to tell if the person accessing data is an AI in lieu of a real person.
physical data can be sent via devices if needed to authenticate, but assume the AI also has access to such devices.


"Definitively prove a person is human": A natural person is a human by definition. A legal person is never a human. There are no other kinds of persons. You probably want to check whether the user agent accessing the resource is under the interactive control of a natural person. This cannot be done with 100% certainty. (And you are using the word authenticate in an unusual way. Captchas are very rarely used for authenticated access, because nobody cares; once the user authenticates, all interaction is in their name, so why would anybody care if they do it by hand or they automate it?)

VTC:Opinion-Based. (a) You've not defined the nature of your AI. There is no ubiquitous definition, especially for something in a future we're only dreaming about. (b) Therefore, based on popular assumptions, you're asking us to come up with a way of testing god. And the answer is identical to all "how do I defeat my godlike character?" questions: you can't without creating an exploitable weakness. Since it is impossible to guess-up a test to prove an undefined god isn't trying to impersonate a mere mortal, it's up to you to decide what the exploitable weakness is.

To help you formulate your own ideas more cogently, look into :Turing test versions, then look at the links at the end of the page there - that's a whole rich set of starting points (eg. visual tests). Cont;

Cont: Then for a bit of perspective: Magical thinking and the test of humanity: we have seen the dangers of AI and it is us. which strikes me as the ultimate issue to grapple with for your question..

If I knew it I would be running to thr patent office and build a comfortable retirement, I would not be sharing it under a creative common licence

True CAPCHA tests aren't those pictures any more. They are based on behaviour. You often do not see them any more, or just need to click a box. Based on (recent) history, time spent, and on (mouse) behaviour on earlier sites they know. I think these are often part of the necessary cookies. The pictures have been beatable by algorithms that aren't AI for quite some time.

What you ask is for there to be an answer to Alan Turing's question of the Imitation Game.  To date, there is no answer and no known way to formulate an answer.  The only answer that can occur is for a computer to successfully imitate a human in every way-shape-or-form.
One approach you could take is to amortize the physical actions, turning most of them into intellectual data-drive operations.  This is not quite what you asked for, but may be a way to sidestep the issues of the Imitation Game.  In this approach, a human being physically interacts with a trusted human to prove they are human.  Think of it like going to the DMV.  The trusted human then provides them with some currency for virtual interactions -- tokens.  Perhaps it's block-chain based.  When a CAPTCHA is issued, the human provides one of these tokens.  If the token is valid and has not already been spent, the user is "human enough".
The logic behind this is that every "human" operation on the internet is more accurately human-assisted.  The computer is doing a billion small activities for every activity the human actually does.  The issue with CAPTCHAs is not that AIs or computer are doing the activity, its the rate at which a computer can do such an activity.  While a human might do something twice a minute, a computer might do it a hundred thousand times a second.  This would rapidly deplete the token pool that someone had acquired (from the "DMV" like establishment).
Do you actually care whether an AI does the task?  Or is it that you want to put AIs on a "fair" footing with their human cohorts.

The OP has failed to define his/her AI, so I wonder why it's beyond the AI to add SLEEP (10+INT(RND()*20+0.5)) to every action deemed normally human and there's enough disparity between action locations that the seed can't be guessed. The problem is that SciFi generally defines an AI as a synthetic intelligence that can pass a Turing test and, oddly, despite Asimov's enormous influence on the genre, the AI is never bound by anything like Asimov's three laws of robotics. Your concluding questions are entirely relevant.

Massive use of botting by people exploiting advertising networks and adblockers by people seeking to avoid advertising resulted in the solution: implants or wearable brain scanning devices to positively determine that the target's brain has actually viewed and paid attention to a given advertisement. The captcha is to periodically watch more advertisements with enough focus to satisfy the system that a biological brain is present.
Or at least, that's how the system originally worked. AI models can now imitate the responses of a brain paying attention, so the newer captcha instead looks for specific signatures of boredom, impatience, and annoyance provoked by the incessant ads and captcha failures followed by more ads.

Make a Mistake
Users are Dumb, AI is smart.
IIRC the current CAPTCHA where it is just a tickbox relies on the fact that a Human moving a mouse cant do so in an optimum, perfect line - whereas a computer cursor would have to build in some form of pseudo-randomness to 'mimic' a Human.
So let us lean into that - the Test is to fail the test, e.g. make a mistake. Could be in the form of mouse movement (or other input device movement) - it could be in the form of a question that only an AI could answer (and the average human would fail to do so - thus proving they are human)
Use AIs greatest strength (perfect recall, perfect movement etc.) against it and design a test where the only way to pass... is to fail

Since the only way to defeat a godlike character is to depose that character from its exalted standing by introducing an exploitable weakness, is the weakness you're proposing that the AI cannot introduce millions of CAPTCHA tests, record the human responses to those tests, and derive a model for responding to all CAPTCHA tests? Or that it can't predict what less intelligent creatures would do? My point is this makes me think of the the old paradox: can God create a rock so large that He cannot lift it? I'm not a fan of "how to defeat my godlike character" questions.

@JBH - My answer is predicated on that the designed of the CAPTCHA is specifically trying to make it AI-proof and so would not publicly disclose that info to the AI. I dont think this is a Godlike question (although I see how one could view it as such). I might flesh out my answer a little, I might not.

If failure is a goal it is reasonable to expect that an AI can optimise for such goal.

@VLAZ - only if the AI knows that is the goal.

It's unreasonable to assume AI would not know. Perfect completion would fail the CAPTCHA. Ergo, that is not the goal. AI excels at exploring systems and their boundaries. So, at best "security through obscurity (of how a system works)" should be regarded at best as wishful thinking when it comes to stopping AI. Unless by "AI" you're really only picturing LLMs, which are heavy on the A but light on the I part.

@VLAZ - Sure, but all computer systems have a degree of Security through obscurity - take Encryption - the obscurity is the Private Key. Even non-reversible encryption (e.g. hashing and salting the results) if the process by which it is done is known, then it can be attacked. If we are assuming the AI can do all these things simultaneously (and without rate limits...) then we are getting close to JBH's god objection.

Private keys for encryption are hardly what I'd call protection by "obscurity". People who want to get in my front door need a key. It's not through obscurity that can't just walk in. Hashing is usually a known algorithm. You can cook up your own hash but what makes, say, bcrypt secure is not the lack of knowledge how it works or whether it's employed. You are making a HUGE leap of logic with AI being, essentially, incompetent. And humanity being hypercompetent in keeping the secret of how future CAPCHAs work. There are big assumptions to make.

@VLAZ I see what you are saying - but if it is not know, except by one person that the way to pass the test is to make human-like mistakes, then it stands to reason that this is private information, in the same way that a private key is private.

The problem is the assumption that the AI is less capable than humanity. If it is equal or more capable, then the goal of failure = success is as easily discovered by the AI as it is any human. Information is remarkably ubiquitous and somehow you need to explain the nature of the CAPTCHA to the users. The idea of detecting human failibility is interesting, but as was once intoned by Mr. Spock, "It was far easier for you, as civilized men, to behave like barbarians than it was for them as barbarians to behave like civilized men."
